# Upgraded to MVC3 Beta, Razor views generate a different base class than a newly created project

Tags: razor

I have been working on a website using MVC Preview 1 since it came out.  Now that beta is out, I have updated my system to beta.

There is not alot of help out there for upgrading from Preview 1 to beta, and just rebuilding caused a lot of problems.  What I have done so far:

1) Copied the web.config from a new MVC3 Beta project (to get the correct sections and values).
2) Added references to System.Web.Helpers and System.Web.WebPages, so that my references would match the newly created project.
3) Changed all my @import to @model as per the new format.

The problem I am getting, is that the views in the existing project, are being derived off of System.Web.Web.Pages and those in the new project are being derived off System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<>.

What am I missing that would be causing this base class issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to copy the /views/web.config  from a new Mvc 3 project - its where the base page class is defined

Comment: Thanks,  I got the main web.config, but didn't see one in the views directory.